# Select specific column plus all related models in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I want to retrieve specific columns from main model plus all related sub models as follows,

```
public function entries() {       
    return $this->hasMany('App\AwardEntry', 'award_id')
                ->join('users', 'users.id', 'user_id')
                ->where('users.department_id', Auth::user()->department_id)
                ->with(['files', 'reviews', 'user']);
}
```

This is working fine with `Award::with('entries')->findOrFail($id)`.

Now I want to retrieve `entry_status` from entry table plus all its sub relation modals.

So I added `select` statement as follows,

```
->select('award_entries.status')
```

Now it is working fine, but `entries` returning empty list.

Comment: Can you use something like this `Award::with('entries')->findOrFail($id)->select('award_entries.status')->get() ` am i right ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Award::select('award_entries.status')->where('id', $id)->with('entries')->get();
```